# Coherent usage of Hibernate's session and DAO

Tags: java, session, hibernate

```
public void something()
{
    Session session = HibernateUtil.newSession();
    AModelDAO amd = new AModelDAO(session);
    BModelDAO bmd = new BModelDAO(session);

    Transaction tx = session.beginTransaction();
    amd.savesomething(object);
    bmd.savesomething(object2);
    tx.commit();
    session.close();
}
```

I would like to know if my coding here is good enough or if there is a better method to produce the same result.

Comment: I do not know hibernate. This is a general guideline that you should handle exception here and also think of the case where the transaction fails and how you revert back the state.

Comment: of course I handled exception...  In my example code, I skipped exception.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of working with Hibernate sessions, I encourage you to use the JPA API. I think this is the most common way to work with Hibernate now. (http://www.theserverside.com/news/2240186700/The-JPA-20-EntityManager-vs-the-Hibernate-Session-Which-one-to-use)

For the transaction aspects and the initialization of your DAOs, I also think that a solution like Spring (http://projects.spring.io/spring-framework/) would help to simplify the code of your application.

Your code would look more like the following (with annotations stuff):

```
public class MyService {
  @Resource
  private AModelDAO aDao;

  @Transactional
  public void something(object) {
    // no need to manage transactions or sessions here
    aDao.save(object);
  }
}
```